# schtask once in a few seconds

Tags: windows-10, task-scheduler

I see that window task scheduler via gui lets you plan an activity with a second precision. If I plan this with via command line even if I specify /st 18:13:39 it becomes /st 18:13:00.
That given, how could I solve or work around this? Consider that I also tried solutions like timeout command or ping command. timeout is not viable because I can't run it in background since input redirection ends the process and to ping 30 times sounds a little bit harsh.

EDIT:
my command looks like this

```
schtasks /create /tn "arch_17" /tr "php my_command" /sc once /sd 05:04:2017 /st 09:14:48
```

is according to the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx) and receives no errors.. it gets executed but when I check it in the planning utilities seconds are set to 00.

Comment: If the GUI allows it, and your command is rounding the seconds down, it means your syntax is likely not valid.

Comment: @Ramhound I added informations in case you want to double check them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `schtasks /Create /?` (at least on Windows 7):

```
/ST starttime Specifies the start time to run the task. The time format is HH:mm (24 hour time) for example, 14:30 for 2:30 PM. Defaults to current time if /ST is not specified.  This option is required with /SC ONCE.
/SD startdate Specifies the first date on which the task runs. The format is dd/mm/yyyy. Defaults to the current date. This is not applicable for schedule types: ONCE, ONSTART, ONLOGON, ONIDLE, ONEVENT.
```

So your `/SD` is in an invalid format and `/ST` doesn't support second precision. It's likely that you will need some other tool to setup the task.

You could try to use [PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/01/13/use-powershell-to-create-scheduled-tasks/) with [`New-ScheduledTaskTrigger`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649821%28v=wps.630%29.aspx), [`New-ScheduledTaskAction`](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtaskaction) and [`Register-ScheduledTask`](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask).

Comment: oh dear, I was looking an archived doc related to win xp. Thank you, I'll try something else